# Where can I find a map of my MBP french keyboard layout?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, internationalization

I just moved to Mac and I need to get used to the keyboard of my Macbook Pro. I've seen images / maps of the QWERTY keyboards but could not find a proper one for French. I want to see what the modifier and options keys does etc. For example finding pipe (|)  was by luck but where the heck are the square brackets?!

Here is my layout:

[image: French MBP]

Comment: Alt+Shift+( et Alt+Shift+). Vindiou not that easy to find :) Good luck if you're stuck coding Objective-C with a french keyboard... I mapped them to F5/F6...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To activate the Keyboard Viewer, click on the Input Menu on the right side of your menu bar, and then click on "Show Keyboard Viewer".

[image]

Simple as that! :)

Comment: If you do not yet have an Input Menu in your menu bar, go to System Preferences > Language and Text > Input Sources to add it.  Probably French OS X has different names for these...